# Ожидание окончания выполнения потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

Почему в результате выполнения данного кода выводится не 100, а каждый раз разное число? Метод же synchronized и даже переменная volatile.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Int {
    static volatile int sum = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++) { 
            executor.execute(new Th());
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    public synchronized  static void inc() {
        sum++;
    }       

    public static class Th implements Runnable {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            inc();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так происходит, потому что вы не дожидаетесь завершения работы потоков. Вы дожидаетесь только окончания их запуска

Чтобы дождаться завершения, вы можете сначала инициировать завершение работы пула потоков методом `shutdown()`, затем вызвать метод `ExecutorService awaitTermination()` с каким-то разумным для вас таймаутом, чтобы дождаться окончания работы уже запущенных потоков.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++) { 
    executor.execute(new Th());
}
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(10, SECONDS);
System.out.println(sum);
```